# How to set the text color of action bar title using style

Tags: android, android-styles

Hello I am trying to set the the `ActionBar` title color to White. I tried below code but that is not working. Currently title of it showing in black color. I don't know what I am missing. I tried diferent many attempts but didn't get success, other properties are working fine like background color etc.

I am using `AppCompat` library for backport.

Can anyone help me please.

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_dark_color</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
            which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!-- ActionBar Text Style -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/titleStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarCompat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="atitleTextStyle">@style/titleStyle</item>



    </style>

    <style name="titleStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a Toolbar you can use the following code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.onecalculator"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyActionBarTitleText" />
```

where MyActionBarTitleText is:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>       
</style>
```

Comment: I am not using ToolBar.

Comment: then try to change `<style name="ActionBarCompat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">` with `<style name="ActionBarCompat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">`

it worked with holo theme, maybe it's the same with appcompat